# Does n-1 edges for a graph on n vertices imply connected?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I know that a connected graph on n vertices has at least n-1 edges so n-1 edges would be a sufficient condition, but is it necessary? I can't seem to think of a counterexample but don't want to assume that it must therefore be true without a solid proof.

Any pointers towards the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $n-1$ edges is necessary, not sufficient. Try find a counter-example, there is one on $4$ vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph with a cycle of length $n-1$ and an isolated vertex has $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges but is not connected.